Datatable jquery plugin. Sorting by image alt but with some rows without images. Is this possible with a change to the extension?
There is a well documented extension for Datatables that allows for the sorting of data which contains images.
This works well if all the entries have an alt tag.
In my case my data looks like this:
    <tr class="tablebody tablebodyhover">
        <td>Item1 description</td>
        <td><img src='icon-tick.svg' alt='tick' width='16' height='16'/></td>
        <td class="textcenter"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="tablebody tablebodyhover">
        <td>Item2 description</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="tablebody tablebodyhover">
        <td>Item3 description</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tablebody tablebodyhover">
        <td>Item4 description</td>
        <td><img src='icon-tick.svg' alt='tick' width='16' height='16'/></td>
    </tr>

As you can see from the HTML not every line has an image and as a result the extension fails to sort because it cannot match alt tag (as there isn't one).
The Datatables extension for sorting looks like this:
    // sort by alt of image extension

    $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
        "alt-string-pre": function ( a ) {
            return a.match(/alt="(.*?)"/)[1].toLowerCase();
        },

        "alt-string-asc": function( a, b ) {
            return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
        },

        "alt-string-desc": function(a,b) {
            return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
        }
    });

It relies on a regex to match the alt string.
Is it possible to modify the extension to allow for rows that have no alt tag and still sort accordingly.
I appreciate that one work around would be to add a dummy image to each line in the HTML but I am interested to find out whether this could be achieved without using dummy images to provide the missing alt tags?
EDIT:
The full working solution:
    $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
        "alt-string-pre": function ( a ) {
            return a.match(/alt="(.*?)"/)?.[1]?.toLowerCase() ?? '';
        },

        "alt-string-asc": function( a, b ) {
            return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
        },

        "alt-string-desc": function(a,b) {
            return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
        }
    });

This now sorts by image alt even with no images present.

match returns null on no match. So you could try defaulting a null to an empty string instead. ==> return a.match(/alt="(.*?)"/)?[1].toLowerCase() ?? ''; -- Notice the ? in front of [1]. See Optional chaining

Now, tweaking the source of a lib has never been encouraged. Better is to use a custom sort function for those cases.

@LouysPatriceBessette - excellent comment. Please submit this as an answer for me to accept.
I did some reading from the link you sent and inserted a full stop between the ? and the [1] to get it working. I have now created my own custom extension alt-string-null.

It's great that you have a solution - but please do not add it to the body of the question. Instead, you are welcome to answer your own question. You can, of course, also choose to accept and/or up-vote any answer posted separately by @LouysPatriceBessette.

In the expression:
a.match(/alt="(.*?)"/)[1].toLowerCase();

if there is no match (no element with an alt attribute), a null is returned by the match method... resulting in:
null[1].toLowerCase();

which throws the error Cannot read properties of null (reading '1').
To avoid this, look for Optional Chaining to stop the chained execution on undefined and null and set a default value to be returned (like an empty string) using a Nullish coalescing operator (??).
So that would be:
a.match(/alt="(.*?)"/)?.[1]?.toLowerCase() ?? '';

